# How do I know the dpi of my laptop screen

Tags: laptop, laptop-display, dpi

My laptop is HP 250 G2 with 15.6” diagonal LED-backlit HD2 anti-glare (1366 x 768). 
Please How do I know the dpi value?

Comment: For you It would be 100 ppi/dpi. Calculated using [this website](http://dpi.lv).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1366 x 768 pixels is 1567 pixels diagonally (Pythagorean theorem, √(1366<sup>2</sup>+768<sup>2</sup>)=1567; and you thought you would never use that).

If the screen measures 15.6" diagonally, 1567 pixels / 15.6" is approximately 100 pixels per inch.

You won't get an exact PPI number unless the manufacturer publishes it or you measure the screen.  The advertised diagonal measurement is often a nominal number and may include a little of the display panel behind the bezel.

Comment: Never thought pythagorean theorem has something to do with displays!

Comment: Pythagorean theorem has everything to do with Euclidean spaces, such as monitor surface

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you are using Windows 7:

- Go to `Control Panel` > `Appearance and Personalization` > `Display`
- In the left(blue) column, click `Set custom text size(DPI)`

A window titled `Custom DPI Scaling` will pop up.
It will show what percent of the "normal size"(default monitor DPI) it is scaled to and will allow you to adjust it.

You should see a ruler in the middle. Below that it will say 9 point Segoe UI at X pixels per inch.

The **X** is your current DPI.

Comment: Which version of windows? Mine says "9 point Segoe UI" rather than at X pixels per inch.

Comment: _Windows 7_. The exact message it says on my computer is "9 point Segoe UI at 144 pixels per inch"

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the version then. Its not there in windows 10.

Comment: OK. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try yourself: [***DPI Calculator***](http://dpi.lv/)

Formula:

> PPI = √(pixels_horizontal^2 + pixels_vertical^2) / inches_diagonal

**PPI** = *√(1366<sup>2</sup> + 768<sup>2</sup>) / 15.6* = **100.45**

Therefore, **100.45 dpi**

Answer (score 3):

as of [DPI Calculator](https://www.sven.de/dpi/)

- Display size: 13.6" × 7.65" = 103.96in² (34.54cm × 19.42cm = 670.72cm²)
- DPI = PPI = 100.45
- 0.2529mm dot pitch, 10091 PPI²